# SSRS 'rsAccessed Denied' for Users Present in Security

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I am having an interesting issue with SSRS and security settings. I have 2008 R2 installed on a Windows Server 2008 box. All users log into their workstations using their active directory credentials, some are local admins, some are just standard users. I have no problem accessing either the management or directory site as DOMAIN\administrator.

I have all reports, folders and data sources set to inherit the security settings on the server, but when I go to a users machine and type in the server address (host/reportserver), I get rsAccess Denied DOMAIN\USER user has insufficient permissions.

I have tried a number of different things based on posts I've read.

- Added NT Authority\Authenticated Users and NT Authority\Network
  Service to security permissions
- Gave users 'Administrator' level access on the report server
- Disabled UAC on the workstation

I read that launching IE as administrator might solve the issue. That would require all users to be local admins, no? I think that is an unacceptable solution.

As always, I appreciate assistance anyone can offer.

Comment: Is there any permission given to domain\user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Add the username(domain\username) to the folder settings(New role assignment-->browser)

of the report manager. This will give access to all the folders on the report manager.

for example if your username is (domain\rocky) then add this domain\rocky to the report manager.

2) make sure the username(domain\rocky) exists in the windows active directory.

3) For safety reasons : Don't provide administrator privileges to users.